# Convert the FULL Excel date serial format to Unix timestamp

Tags: php, import-from-excel

I've seen lots of references to converting the "date" portion of the Excel serial date format, but everyone seems to skip the "time" portion of it.

Here is what I need to do:

I have an Excel file I'm importing.  PHP in use.

I am encountering the Excel Date Serial format (dddddd.tttttt) and need to convert this to an entire Unix timestamp.

I've tried a few different things, but am getting hung up on how to do this in a fluid motion.

Comment: what does strtotime() give you?

Comment: strtotime is __not__ going to help with n excel serial value, which is the number of days since 1/1/1900 (or possibly 1/1/1904 depending on whether it uses the windows 1900 or Mac 1904 calendar)

Answer (score 59):

Please use this formula to change from Excel date to Unix date, then you can use "gmdate" to get the real date in PHP:

```
UNIX_DATE = (EXCEL_DATE - 25569) * 86400
```

and to convert from Unix date to Excel date, use this formula:

```
EXCEL_DATE = 25569 + (UNIX_DATE / 86400)
```

After doing this formula into a variable, you can get the real date in PHP using this example:

```
$UNIX_DATE = ($EXCEL_DATE - 25569) * 86400;
echo gmdate("d-m-Y H:i:s", $UNIX_DATE);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Works like a charm  `function ExcelDateToUnix($dateValue = 0) {
        return ($dateValue - 25569) * 86400;
    }`

Comment: once again ... nice answer ... ;)

Comment: Wow. I searched far and wide for this. Excellent answer that finally got me to displaying the right date. (for me it was Google Sheets API in PHP) Thank you!

Comment: To explain the numbers: 

By default, **Microsoft Excel** for Windows uses the 1900 date system, which means the first date is **January 1, 1900**.

By default, **Unix epoch time** uses the 1970 date system, which means the first date is **January 1, 1970**.

- **25569** is number of days of 70 years between 1900 and 1970. 
- **86400** is number of seconds in one day (24 hours)

Answer (score 14):

This oneliner worked for me, using PHPExcel of course.

```
$date_formated = date('Y-m-d', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($date_int_val));
```

Comment: PhpExcel is now deprecated. Its direct successor PhpSpreadsheet, allow us to use the following method: `\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($date_int_val)`.

Comment: If you search the Phpspreadsheet docs (using their search bar), the function excelToDateTimeObject *does not show up*. Even 'datetimeobject' doesn't show up. You have to search 'datetime' or something similar, then scroll thru the page. For reference, it's currently at https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/calculation-engine/#php-datetime-objects . Then you can search that page. Not sure why such an important function is that hard to find. I wouldn't have known about it if not for @Guicara comment

Comment: @McAuley indeed the doc is not very good! I'm glad my comment helped you.

Answer (score 7):

You clearly haven't looked very hard:

Taken directly from the PHPExcel Date handling code:

```
public static function ExcelToPHP($dateValue = 0) {
    if (self::$ExcelBaseDate == self::CALENDAR_WINDOWS_1900) {
        $myExcelBaseDate = 25569;
        //    Adjust for the spurious 29-Feb-1900 (Day 60)
        if ($dateValue < 60) {
            --$myExcelBaseDate;
        }
    } else {
        $myExcelBaseDate = 24107;
    }

    // Perform conversion
    if ($dateValue >= 1) {
        $utcDays = $dateValue - $myExcelBaseDate;
        $returnValue = round($utcDays * 86400);
        if (($returnValue <= PHP_INT_MAX) && ($returnValue >= -PHP_INT_MAX)) {
            $returnValue = (integer) $returnValue;
        }
    } else {
        $hours = round($dateValue * 24);
        $mins = round($dateValue * 1440) - round($hours * 60);
        $secs = round($dateValue * 86400) - round($hours * 3600) - round($mins * 60);
        $returnValue = (integer) gmmktime($hours, $mins, $secs);
    }

    // Return
    return $returnValue;
}    //    function ExcelToPHP()
```

Set self::$ExcelBaseDate == self::CALENDAR_WINDOWS_1900 as necessary to indicate the Excel base calendar that you're using: Windows 1900 or Mac 1904

and if you want a PHP DateTime object instead:

```
public static function ExcelToPHPObject($dateValue = 0) {
    $dateTime = self::ExcelToPHP($dateValue);
    $days = floor($dateTime / 86400);
    $time = round((($dateTime / 86400) - $days) * 86400);
    $hours = round($time / 3600);
    $minutes = round($time / 60) - ($hours * 60);
    $seconds = round($time) - ($hours * 3600) - ($minutes * 60);

    $dateObj = date_create('1-Jan-1970+'.$days.' days');
    $dateObj->setTime($hours,$minutes,$seconds);

    return $dateObj;
}    //    function ExcelToPHPObject()
```

Comment: thanks Mark.  Keep in mind that I may not have the depth of experience, though for the most part I'm able to find things.  In this case, as I'm parsing through my spreadsheet do I call the function and pass it the cell value?

Comment: How are you actually reading the Excel workbook in the first place?

Comment: opening with PHPExcel, iterating on each row, getting each cell value, so in the case of column A, which has the date value, I'm basically doing $cell = $sheet->getCell('A' . $rowIndex), then $array_data[$rowIndex]['A'] = $cell->getValue();  From there I just want to set it to a variable already in Unix timestamp format

Comment: Mark, thanks.  I took what I needed from the above and created a private function to use where I needed it.  Cheers

Comment: If you're using PHPExcel, then don't bother with a private function: the code I quoted above is built into PHPExcel - PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP() or PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject() - just call those instead

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue on a project, I was looking for a **`PHP Class to Read Excel as PHP Array`**.
I was lucky that I found **`'SimpleXLSX' Class`**. It can handle excel data very well, but.. but... ohh!! but.... :(
I have realised that there is some issue with **`Date Reading From Excel`** field. In excel values was looking fine but when we were
trying to import them, The Date Values Getting Different. Some time we were getting correct values some times just a number and some times a float values.
We were looking for solution  '

> **WHY IT IS HAPPENING, WHY PHP NOT GETTING CORRECT DATE FROM EXCEL**

'
Then after the lots of goggling we found the reason:

**@Source: [reading xls date in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808750/reading-xls-date-in-php)**

> According to excel format 41397 is 2013-05-03 Excel stores dates and
>   times as a number representing the number of days since 1900-Jan-0,
>   plus a fractional portion of a 24 hour day: ddddd.tttttt. This is
>   called a serial date, or serial date-time.

**@Source: [Excel date conversion using PHP Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119631/excel-date-conversion-using-php-excel)**

> Convert Excel Date To Unix Date and Then Convert Unix Date to PHP Date

So, I made a little helper class to read Excel Date for use in PHP. I hope it will help someone and will reduce goggling and efforts.

Here is my code to `Read Excel as PHP Array()` and `Parse Excel Date as PHP Date`

> For Beginners:

1. Download `SimpleXLSX.php` from given example code
2. Convert excel data (field/value) in PHP array()
3. Convert excel date into PHP
4. Now.. Yeah!! Excel Data is Ready as an PHP Array to moving into
   MySQL table...

> Here is PHP Code:

```
<?php   
/*
  EXCEL DATA EXAMPLE:
  ----------------------------
  ID      Consumer_Date  Delivery_Date   Date_of_Dispatch    Gift_Date_Created   Active_Date              Approved_Date
  536     -No-Data-      9-Nov-15        7-Nov-15            -No-Data-           10/31/2015 12:00:00 AM   4/11/2015 10:21
  537     -No-Data-      -No-Data-       7-Nov-15            -No-Data-           10/23/2015 12:00:00 AM   3/11/2015 16:24

*/

/*
  EXCEL DATA IN PHP ARRAY FORMAT
  -------------------------------
  Array
  (
      [0] => Array
          (
              [ID] => 536
              [Consumer_Date] => -No-Data-
              [Delivery_Date] => 42317
              [Date_of_Dispatch] => 42315
              [Gift_Date_Created] => -No-Data-
              [Active_Date] => 10/31/2015 12:00:00 AM
              [Approved_Date] => 42105.431574074
          )
      [1] => Array
          (
              [ID] => 537
              [Consumer_Date] => -No-Data-
              [Delivery_Date] => -No-Data-
              [Date_of_Dispatch] => 42315
              [Gift_Date_Created] => -No-Data-
              [Active_Date] => 10/23/2015 12:00:00 AM
              [Approved_Date] => 42074.683958333
          )
  )

*/

/* ----------------- */
/* Excel_Date_Parser.php */
/* ----------------- */


// Numbers of days between January 1, 1900 and 1970 (including 19 leap years)
define("MIN_DATES_DIFF", 25569);

// Numbers of second in a day:
define("SEC_IN_DAY", 86400);

/** Set default timezone (will throw a notice otherwise) */
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

/**
 * Class Excel_Date_Parser
 *
 * SetDateString($excel_date_value) : send excel date column value
 * GetDateString(): get your php date in Y-m-d format (MySQL)
 */
class Excel_Date_Parser
{

  /**
   * Send Excel Date String Value Here
   * @param [type] $date_from_excel [description]
   * @return instance Excel_Date_Parser
   */
  public function SetDateString($date_from_excel) {
    $this->date_from_excel = $date_from_excel;
    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * Set Date Format Here, default is "Y-m-d"
   * @param string $set_format_date [description]
   */
  public function SetDateFormat($set_format_date = "Y-m-d") {
    $this->set_format_date = $set_format_date;
  }

  /**
   * Get what format is set
   */
  public function GetDateFormat() {
    return $this->set_format_date;
  }

  /**
   * Return PHP date according to Set Format from Excel Date
   * @return string php date
   */
  public function GetDateString() {

    // if value is valid date string
    if (strtotime($this->date_from_excel)) {

      /**
       * Excel stores dates and times as a number representing the number of days since 1900-Jan-0,
       * plus a fractional portion of a 24 hour day: ddddd.tttttt.
       * This is called a serial date, or serial date-time.
       *
       * @source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808750/reading-xls-date-in-php
       */
      if (is_float($this->date_from_excel)) {

        // date format 2015-25-12
        $this->SetDateFormat("Y-d-m");
        $this->date_from_excel = date($this->GetDateFormat() , (mktime(0, 0, -1, 1, $this->date_from_excel, 1900)));
      } 
      else {

        // date format 2015-12-25
        $this->SetDateFormat();

        // return converted date string in php format date format 2015-12-25
        $this->date_from_excel = date($this->GetDateFormat() , strtotime($this->date_from_excel));
      }
    }

    /**
     * Excel stores dates and times as a number representing the number of days since 1900-Jan-0,
     * plus a fractional portion of a 24 hour day: ddddd.tttttt .
     * This is called a serial date, or serial date-time.
     *
     * According to excel format 41397 is 2013-05-03
     * @source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808750/reading-xls-date-in-php
     */
    else if (is_integer($this->date_from_excel)) {
      $this->SetDateFormat();
      $this->date_from_excel = gmdate($this->GetDateFormat() , (($this->date_from_excel - MIN_DATES_DIFF) * SEC_IN_DAY));
    }

    // return real value
    else {
      $this->date_from_excel = $this->date_from_excel;
    }

    // return date
    return $this->date_from_excel;
  }
}


/* ----------------- */
/* Excel_Reader.php */
/* ----------------- */

/* Show errors */
error_reporting(1);

/* display error */
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

/**
* Using class SimpleXLSX 
* 
* Big Thanks!!!! to Sergey Shuchkin, Who made Excel Reader Class
* 
* This class can be used to parse and retrieve data from Excel XLS spreadsheet files.
* It can parse a given Excel XLS file by extracting its contents files and parsing the 
* contained XML spreadsheet file.
*
* The class provides functions to retrieve data for the spreadsheet worksheets, rows and cells.
*
* @link: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6279-PHP-Parse-and-retrieve-data-from-Excel-XLS-files.html
* @author: Sergey Shuchkin
* @download: http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/download/zip/package/6279/name/simple-xlsx-2013-10-13.zip
*/
require_once 'SimpleXLSX.php';


/* Adding my class Excel_Date_Parser */
require_once 'Excel_Date_Parser.php';


/**
 * [toPhpDate description]
 * @param [type] $array [description]
 */
function toPhpDate($array) {

  // create class object
  $ed = new Excel_Date_Parser();

  // parse array and set
  $array['Consumer_Date'] = $ed->SetDateString($array['Consumer_Date'])->GetDateString();
  $array['Delivery_Date'] = $ed->SetDateString($array['Delivery_Date'])->GetDateString();
  $array['Date_of_Dispatch'] = $ed->SetDateString($array['Date_of_Dispatch'])->GetDateString();
  $array['Gift_Date_Created'] = $ed->SetDateString($array['Gift_Date_Created'])->GetDateString();
  $array['Active_Date'] = $ed->SetDateString($array['Active_Date'])->GetDateString();
  $array['Approved_Date'] = $ed->SetDateString($array['Approved_Date'])->GetDateString();

  // return php array
  return $array;
}

// make xls object
$xlsx = new SimpleXLSX('Sony_RedemptionFormat 8-Dec-15.xlsx');

// get excel data as array
$Excel_Array_Data = $xlsx->rows();

// Get Column Name
$Excel_Column = $Excel_Array_Data[0];

// Remove Column Name From Array
unset($Excel_Array_Data[0]);

// Rest Data is Excel Data without Column
$Excel_Data = $Excel_Array_Data;

// Combine array for inserting in database
foreach ($Excel_Array_Data as $key => $Excel_Data) {
  $insert_data[] = array_combine($Excel_Column, $Excel_Data);
}

// show array data
echo "<pre>", print_r($insert_data, true);

// update array excel date
$insert_data = array_map('toPhpDate', $insert_data);

// show array data after update date
echo "<pre>", print_r($insert_data, true);
```

Hope this code will help someone. I was struggling same problem So I made this little script to save others time.

> Happy PHPING!!!! :)

Comment: User is asking for a solution using PHPExcel.  Installing a whole new library it's not a solution.