# reading xls date in php

Tags: php, date, phpexcel

I'm using [php-excel-reader](https://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/) to read an XLS file in my php script, everything is working fine, except for reading a date. It simply return an undefined object.

- The XLS file isn't made on my computer and I don't know with witch
  version it was created.
- If I open the file on my computer and save it again, everything works fine. (but I would obviously prefer to avoid having to do that)
- After doing some digging in the php-excel-reader script, I managed to get the value it extracts from the XLS. For example, 41397 instead of 03/05/2013 (d/m/y)

A few questions :

- Is this fixable ?
- Is it possible to exploit the 41397 ? Is it a known date format ?
- Is there another xsl to php script where this will work without having to change anything ?

Comment: This is caused by the wrong cell format. Try to create a date in Excel in date format. Then change the cell format to number and you'll see something like 41397.

Comment: it's what I though yes, but I need to make it work without having to manually change back the cell format and everything.

Comment: Either use a library that can handle date conversions between Excel and PHP, such as [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net) - you've tagged this PHPExcel, but aren't actually using PHPExcel; or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172644/php-convert-the-full-excel-date-serial-format-to-unix-timestamp/11172688#11172688

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to excel format `41397 is 2013-05-03`

> Excel stores dates and times as a number representing the number of
>   days since 1900-Jan-0, plus a fractional portion of a 24 hour day:
>   ddddd.tttttt . This is called a serial date, or serial date-time.

You can use the following code to convert the number to valid date

```
function excelDateToDate($readDate){
    $phpexcepDate = $readDate-25569; //to offset to Unix epoch
    return strtotime("+$phpexcepDate days", mktime(0,0,0,1,1,1970));
}
```

`php-excel-reader` is supposed to do this, but don't know why it is not doing it.

You can get more info about how excel stores date [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm) (not an authentic reference like msdn)

Edit:
Checked PHPExcel, looks like the static function `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($dateValue = 0, $adjustToTimezone = FALSE, $timezone = NULL)` does this.

Comment: thanks, I tried converting it into a valid date myself, but I didn't know about the -25569.

Comment: -25569 it to adjust from 1900-Jan-0 to Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT) and excel thinks there exists the date 1900-Feb-29

Answer (score 2):

An easy way...

`<?php
    $date = date_create('30-12-1899');
    date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('41397 days'));
    echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
?>`