# I'm Import to Mysql from Excel files, but the results are 1970-01-01

Tags: php

I'm Import to Mysql from Excel files, but the results are 1970-01-01, this my code:

```
// server info
$server = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'agenda';

// connect to the database
$mysqli = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);

// show errors (remove this line if on a live site)
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR);

?>

<?php
require 'classes/phpexcel.php';
require_once 'classes/phpexcel/iofactory.php';
$inputFileName  = 'database/sql/agenda.xlsx';
$inputFileType  = 'Excel2007';
$objReader      = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader("$inputFileType");
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objPHPExcel    = $objReader->load("$inputFileName");
$objWorksheet   = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$highestRow     = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();
$highestColumn  = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn();
$highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);

// view in table
echo '<table>' . "\n";
for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
    echo '<tr>' . "\n";
    for ($col = 0; $col <= $highestColumnIndex; ++$col) {
        echo '<td>' . $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue() . '</td>' . "\n";
    }
    echo '</tr>' . "\n";
}
echo '</table>' . "\n";

//input to mysql
for($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
    for($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++$col) {  
        $rows[$col] = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row); 
    }
    $id   ="$rows[0]";
    $ts   ="$rows[1]";
    $pd   ="$rows[2]";

    $get_data1  = "$rows[3]";
    $st   = date("Y-m-d", strtotime ($get_data1));

    $stm  ="$rows[4]";

    $get_data2  ="$rows[5]";
    $et   = date("Y-m-d", strtotime ($get_data2));

    $etm  ="$rows[6]";
    $g    ="$rows[7]";
    $w    ="$rows[8]";
    // Prepared Statement
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `keyin` VALUES ('$id', '$ts', '$pd', '$st', '$stm', '$et', '$etm', '$g', '$w')");
    //Prepared Statement Bound$stmt->bind_param('sssssssss', $id, $ts, $pd, $st, $stm, $et, $etm, $g, $w);     


    //Prepared Statement Executed 
    $stmt->execute();
    printf("%s Row Inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);
    //Prepared Statement Closed
    $stmt->close();

    // If you don't want to use prepared statement, you can use this one

    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO users (Username,Email,Gender,Country) VALUES ('$rows[0]', '$rows[1]', '$rows[2]', '$rows[3]')");
}
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: sounds like an invalid date/timestamp in `$get_data1`/`$rows[3]`. What do you get for `var_dump($rows[3])`?

Comment: I get from the excel files result is = 42604

Comment: that's not a timestamp or a string-formatted date. Sure it's the right column? What's the equivalent date shown in excel?

Comment: @Jeff timestamps in excel are not counted as in PHP. In excel the "time" starts at 1900 and the number is the number of days and not seconds as in PHP.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172644/convert-the-full-excel-date-serial-format-to-unix-timestamp

Answer (score 1):

Since excel counts the number of days since 1900-01-01 you can not use strtotime().

What you need to do is to convert the excel days to seconds.

```
$unix = ($get_data1 - 25569) * 86400; 
$st = date("Y-m-d", $unix);
```

Your excel value of ~42000 is less than one day in seconds (86400) thus you get 1970-01-01 in php.
If you add time to your php code you will see that the time will be around noon first of january 1970.

https://3v4l.org/teI1F

Comment: $st = PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::toFormattedString($get_data1, 'YYYY-MM-DD');

Comment: Sorry forgot to remove the strtotime() from the code even though I wrote it can not be used.... facepalm

Comment: @EdiHaryono I had no idea that excisted. But then again I use excel a lot and I program a lot in php, but I have never combined the two. Good one! I just know how to solve problems with brute force ;-)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$st = date('Y-m-d', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($get_data1));
```

Comment: welcome. if you find useful, please vote for the answer.