# how to upload date from excel to mysql ? (using php)

Tags: php, mysql, date, cakephp

I am trying to upload few data from excel to mysql i am using php. When i upload date 5/14/2015 it could not upload properly. It went this format 1970-01-01. I am very tired to search in google.

Here is my code.

```
if ($ext == 'xlsx' || $ext == 'xls') {
                            try {
                                $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($target_path);
                                $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType,'CSV');
                                $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
                                $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($target_path);
                            } catch (Exception $e) {
                                die('Error loading file "' . pathinfo($target_path, PATHINFO_BASENAME) . '": ' . $e->getMessage());
                            }
                            $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
                            $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
                            $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
                        }else{
                             //In case of CSV
                            if (($handle = fopen($target_path, "r")) !== FALSE) {
                                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
                                    $csvData[] = $data;
                                }
                                fclose($handle);
                                $highestRow = count($csvData);

                            }
                        }

                        $rowData = array();
                        for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
                            if ($ext == 'xlsx' || $ext == 'xls') {
                                //  Read a row of data into an array
                                $test = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);
                                $rowData[] = $test[0];

                            }
                        }



                        if ($ext == 'csv') {
                            $rowData = $csvData;
                        }
                        $variable = array();
                        $i = 0;
                        $targetArr = array();
                        $error = '';
                        foreach($rowData as $item){
                            if($item[0] !='' && $item[1] !='' && $item[2] !=''):
                                $variable[$i]['Customer'] = array();
                                $variable[$i]['Customer']['msisdn'] = $item[0];
                                $variable[$i]['Customer']['csactivated'] = date('y-m-d',strtotime($item[1]));
                                $variable[$i]['Customer']['csdeactivated'] = date('y-m-d',strtotime($item[2]));
                                //$targetArr[] = $variable;
                                $i++;
                            else:
                                $count =+1;
                                $error .= 'Skip this Row'.$i++.'<br>';
                                continue;
                            endif;
                        }
```

i got date like 42104.592743056 when i import excel though it is not my date format .........and mysql insert like 1970-01-01

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Add some code. What have you tried ? If possible a demo of the problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172644/convert-the-full-excel-date-serial-format-to-unix-timestamp have a look at this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're telling PHPExcel to ignore any formatting in the spreadsheet when you load it (`$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);`), such as the date/time formatting, you'll only be able to get MS Excel's internal timestamp value. You'll need to call PHPExcel's built-in functions to convert date vaues manually:

Either:

```
PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject(42104.592743056);
```

to convert that MS Excel date/time value to a PHP DateTime object

or

```
PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP(42104.592743056);
```

to convert MS Excel value to a Unix timetamp

And then you can use the appropriate PHP functions to format it however you like

---

Alternatively, don't suppress the formatting information when you load the spreadsheet, and tell `rangeToArray()` to apply the formatting

Comment: i don't understand actually where i use this code PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject(42104.592743056);  @ Mark Baker

Comment: You use it where `i got date like 42104.592743056` to convert that `42104.592743056` MS Excel date value to a Unix timestamp or a PHP DateTime object instead of using `strtotime($item[1])`