# What PHP function to parse this timestamp 42866.32972

Tags: php, excel, datetime

I am looking for the correct PHP function to parse this timestamp.

I have a range of timestamps that I need to parse in PHP however I can't find the correct function to use. The timestamps are in the format "42866.32972".

Excel converts "42866.32972" to "2017-05-11 07:54:48" using the format "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss" however I can't find the function to parse this timestamp format in PHP.

I have tried to parse this with DateTime and Date to no avail.

What is the timestamp format and how can I parse this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert the FULL Excel date serial format to Unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11172644/1255289)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Excel dates are similar to Unix Epoch, however they begin on a different date (1900/01/01), compared to (1970/01/01).

```
<?php

function parse_excel_date($value) {
    return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', ceil($value * 86400 - 2209161600));
}

echo parse_excel_date(42866.32972);
```

[Output](https://eval.in/private/778f89bf6b068f):

```
2017-05-11 07:54:48
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula to change from Excel date to Unix date, then you can use "gmdate" to get the real date in PHP:

```
$unix_date = ($excel_date- 25569) * 86400
```

and to convert from Unix date to Excel date, use this formula:

```
$excel_date= 25569 + ($unix_date / 86400)
```

After putting this formula into a variable, you can get the real date in PHP using this example:

```
$unix_date = ($excel_date- 25569) * 86400;
echo gmdate("d-m-Y H:i:s", $unix_date );
```

The 86400 is number of seconds in a day = 24 * 60 * 60.

The 25569 is the number of days from Jan 1, 1900 to Jan 1, 1970.

Excel base date is Jan 1, 1900 and Unix is Jan 1, 1970.

UNIX date values are in seconds from Jan 1, 1970 (midnight Dec 31, 1969).

So to convert from excel you must subtract the number of days and then convert to seconds.