# How to convert from Google Sheet date number value to JavaScript date?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

For dates, Google Sheets gives some number value in roughly pure numerical format like 450345. How does one convert this number into a date value in JavaScript? Tried creating a new Date based off one of these and got a value that does not correspond to the Google Sheets display date value.

Comment: You should be able to get `Date` object if the value can be converted to a `Date` object. Can you please show us how you get the value with a screenshot on part of the affected cells?

Comment: Is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/a/15137090/7108653

Comment: If the cell is a date and time, then Google Sheets uses a numerical value days since 12/30/1899 0:00:00, where the decimal portion is fraction of a day.  Of course if you set the format to date and time you see a calender day and time.  Javascript uses milliseconds since 1/1/1970 0:00:00.  If you getValue() of a date cell then the conversion to milliseconds is done automatically and it is compatible with a javascript date.  But if you get the numeric value you have to convert to milliseconds by multiplying by 24*60*60*1000.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shout-out to TheWizEd for leading me to what looks to be the right answer. Here is a simple conversion script:

```
function logSheetDateString(GS_date_num, timezone, format) {
    var GS_earliest_date = new Date(1899, 11, 30), 
        //GS_earliest_date gives negative time since it is before 1/1/1970
        GS_date_in_ms = GS_date_num*24*60*60*1000;
    Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(GS_date_in_ms + GS_earliest_date.getTime()), 
                                    timezone, format));
}
```

The conversion to milliseconds since January 1, 1970 may be simplified as:

```
JS_date_in_ms = GS_date_num * 86400000 - 2209132800000;
```

Comment: I checked your simplification, but couldn't get it to make sense. It's not 1899-11-30 which is the start date. If I do =TO_DATE(0) I get 1899-12-30 
If I use Google Sheet with that date, it says there's 25569 days 1899-12-30 and 1970-1-1 and I then convert that to milliseconds by 25569*24*60*60*1000 which Google Sheet tells me is 2209161600000 and not 2209132800000 as you state is your simplification.

So the simplification should be 
JS_date_in_ms = GS_date_num * 86400000 - 2209161600000 ;

Comment: I am working on getting a value from event object of on edit and new Date(e.value * 864000000 - 2209132800000) works great.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

These functions convert javascript dates correctly to the inner representation of Google Sheet dates and vice versa.

```
/**
 * @param {Number} GoogleDateValue - Days passed since dec 30 1899, time in fraction
 * @returns {Date object} - javascript date object
 *
 */
function ValueToDate(GoogleDateValue) {
  return new Date(new Date(1899,11,30+Math.floor(GoogleDateValue),0,0,0,0).getTime()+(GoogleDateValue%1)*86400000) ;
}

/**
 * @param {Date object} - javascript date object{Number} 
 * @returns {Number} GoogleDateValue - Days passed since dec 30 1899, time in fraction
 *
 */

function DateToValue(date) {
  return 25569 + (date.getTime()-date.getTimezoneOffset()*60000)/86400000 ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the date [format](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getNumberFormat()) of the cell and then [format](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)) it using the Utilities:

```
var cell = sheet.getRange("C4");
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(cell.getValue(), "GMT", cell.getNumberFormat());
Logger.log(formattedDate);
```

Remember to change `GMT` to your timezone.

Answer (score 1):

```
function job_counter() {


  var yesterday_jobs=0;
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var e = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth() , new Date().getDate())
  var range_unformated=ss.getRange(2,3,25)
  var range = Utilities.formatDate(range_unformated.getValues(), "GMT", range_unformated.getNumberFormats())
  for (var i=1; i<25; i++){
    if ( range[i] - e <= 0 && range[i] != ""  ){
      yesterday_jobs = yesterday_jobs + 1 
    ss.getRange(16,2).setValue(yesterday_jobs)
    Logger.log(d)
    }}
    // check yesterday_jobs                       
}
```

I get the message  "Cannot find method formatDate(object,string,object)"

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
let JSdateFormat = new Date(Date.parse(GSheetDateValInNumFormat + 2207520000000));
console.log(JSdateFormat);
```

2207520000000 is the difference between Google Sheet and Javascript starting time ( |(11:59:59, 30/12/1899) - (00:00:00, 01/01/1970)| ) in milisecond.