# PHP get month and year from a value such as 43556

Tags: php, strtotime

I have a field in the database called "GROWTH_SALES_MONTHSTART" which has a value 43556. What is the right way to get the month and year from this in PHP?

`strtotime( "43556")` gives `bool(false)`.

EDIT:
I tried the following but the date is not coming up right.

```
$tt = date( 'M-y', 43556 ) ;
var_dump( $tt );
```

The actual date which I should receive is Apr-19 while I am getting Jan-70. Am I missing something?

I am pulling the value (43556) from a CSV.

Comment: `strtotime()` only accept a [valid formatted string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) and `43556` is not a valid format datetime string. What is your expect value when turn the number `43556`  to month and year? How did you convert month-year to that number in the first place?

Comment: You tell me how to do it on paper. Then maybe i tell you how to it in PHP. In other words you gave us no clue as to why 43556 maps to apr19. If IT was Unix timestamp it would be around noon 1st Jan 1970. But thats probably not the case... So what Is the logic of that numbers mapping to dates?

Comment: If the csv Is exported from Excel. It May be the excels date representation. "Regardless of how you have formatted a cell to display a date or time, Excel always internally stores dates And times the same way. Excel stores dates and times as a number representing the number of days since 1900-Jan-0, plus a fractional portion of a 24 hour day: ddddd.tttttt " then 43556 Is about 122 years from that which seems more likely to be the case. Try phpspreadsheet library, there should be a class that handles the conversion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert the FULL Excel date serial format to Unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172644/convert-the-full-excel-date-serial-format-to-unix-timestamp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP's builtin `strtotime(...)` method expects valid time format and treats your input as *seconds*, and about the value which you try to convert to time we can say that:

- Your number `43556 seconds` equals `725.9` hours (divided by `60`)
- The `725.9` hours equal `30.2` days.
- The `30` days equal one and only one month.
- The first month of the year is `January`.
- The first year of the PHP clock is `1970`.

And this concludes why you are stuck with `Jan-70`.

---

Anyway, if your times are `Excel` based, you can use below formula to change from *Excel date* to *Unix date*, then you can use "`gmdate(...)`" to get the real date (like [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15137090/8740349)):

```php
$EXCEL_DATE = 43556; // Your CSV value goes here
$UNIX_DATE = ($EXCEL_DATE - 25569) * 86400;
echo gmdate("d-M-Y H:i:s", $UNIX_DATE);
```

Output:

```
01-Apr-2019 00:00:00
```

---

But, if your times are NOT `Excel` based you should:

- Find out on which year and date your CSV times are based.
- Convert that to seconds (where `1970` should be zero), to get `$baseTime`.
- At last, simply add `$baseTime` to your CSV time-values.

For example:

```php
$baseTime = strtotime( 'Tue Dec 15 2009' );
$tt = date( "d-m-Y H:i:s", strtotime( $baseTime + 43556 ) );
var_dump( $tt );
```

Comment: So there is always a way :) You saved my day. Thank you so much @Top-Master!  It works!! But would you please let me know what does `25569` do?

Comment: The `25569` constant is the base-date if the CSV file was saved on `MS Windows` platform, but if the CSV file was saved from other platforms the `24107` constant should be used instead. (there is a more complete code sample taken from `PhpExcel` in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11172688/8740349) for this).

Comment: Just curious. Is there any way to know which platform the XL was saved in?

Comment: The base-date is `1900` for *Windows* or `1904` for *Mac*, `PHPExcel` does use that of *Windows* as default,
The only possible way we could determine it is to know what the valid date should look like, for example, if we would use the *Mac* constant your value would result in year `2023` (not `2019`).