# Convert excel decimal number into date

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a number on which after applying some formula I got `43917.60417`. Excel convert this number into date and datetime format as `3/27/2020 14:30:00`. How can I convert this number into date or datetime using mysql or php. I searched a lot but didn't got any solution.

I tried

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(REPLACE('13577.77916', '.', ''));
 -- this results in 2013-01-10 06:01:56
```

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(REPLACE('43917.60417', '.', '')); 
-- this results in null
```

Comment: I still did not understand what is your problem?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172644/convert-the-full-excel-date-serial-format-to-unix-timestamp

Comment: I suspect its due to max integer size, `2,147,483,647` is the max on a 32bit system, which is less than the value you're trying to use, `4,391,760,417`.

Comment: @GiacomoM I want to convert that number into date which excel does like copy that number in google spreadsheet and click on `Format->Number->Datetime` it will convert to datetime

Comment: Basically what you need is `date('Y-m-d h:i:s', ($excelTime - 25569) * 86400)`

Comment: @NageshKatke what is the source number? which format?

Comment: @Beniamin it works :) thanks. I didn't thought solution will be that simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go in PHP

```
<?php

$unix = (43917.60417 - 25569) * 86400; //convert to unix first

echo gmdate("d-m-Y H:i:s", $unix); //return to your desired date format

?>
```

AND IN MySQL, This should work for both positive and negative epoch

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(0), interval (13577.77916-25569)*86400 second);
```

And to specify date format in MySQL, you can use `DATE_FORMAT(`

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(0), interval (13577.77916-25569)*86400 second),'%Y-%m-%d') as my_new_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

The [DateTime extension dt](https://github.com/jspit-de/dt) knows a special method createFromMsTimestamp for the MS Excel timestamp.

```
$excelTimestamp = 43917.60417;

$date = dt::createFromMsTimestamp($excelTimestamp);

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
//2020-03-27 14:30:00
```