# i want to convert this 5 digit number into date format from excell to database

Tags: php, sql, excel, vue.js

i will provide this specific code.

i first convert the excel file to array of object in php.

in the excell file i have `2022/08/08` format and when i insert it to database it gives me this value
44824

and i convert this `44824` using this code

```
gmdate("Y-m-d", ($arr['excelDatas'][0]['date_hired'] - 25569) * 86400)
```

just ignore the $arr['excelDatas'][0]['date_hired'] - this is just the value

this is the result `2022-09-20`

as you can see the date in excell is different to the converted one
2022/08/08 != 2022-09-20

where did i fall short?

Comment: while inserting from excel to database do like this : `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2022/08/08'))`. So that it saves the correct date and then again while exporting from database to excel, do like this: `date('Y/m/d', strtotime('2022-08-08')`

Comment: I would rather push you to fix the datatype of the column in the excel sheet.

Comment: FYI, In excel, the value `44824` is `2022/9/20` if using date format, so you'd better check what happened when you saved the data to db in the first place.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert excel decimal number into date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60430089/convert-excel-decimal-number-into-date)