# PHPExcel Date Format

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am getting an output from MS SQL server in the '2012-08-09 00:00:00' (without quotes) format.

However, when I write it to excel file I'm unable to write it in date format to have dd mmm yyyy formatting on excel.

As a result i tried to write in format =date(2012,08,09) as a formula to the respective cells.

But I don't want to output it as a formula but rather the value '09 Aug 2012' with the data type integrity intact. How do I do this? Or is there a simpler method?

I read through the documentation but it was not clear to me, thought I would ask for clarification.

Regards.

---

Sorry for not being detailed enough.

I am using the PHPExcel library.

From my sql array, i use the following:

```
$t_year    = substr($xls_column_datas["colname"],0,4);
$t_month   = substr($xls_column_datas["colname"],5,2);
$t_day     = substr($xls_column_datas["colname"],8,2);
$t_format  = $t_year . "," . $t_month . "," . $t_day ;
$t_format  = '=date('.$t_format.')';

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($data_column_num, $data_row_num, $t_format );
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyleByColumnAndRow($data_column_num, $data_row_num)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('[$-C09]d mmm yyyy;@');
```

in my excel output, it shows column A2 for e.g. =DATE(2012,8,9)

rather than showing up as a formula I want excel to recognize '2012-08-09 00:00:00'  is a date time and format it to dd mmm yyyy.

Is this getting clear? Sorry.

Comment: See this link may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279917/format-text-in-excel-file-via-php

Comment: Мне помог [вервый ответ][1] с соседней темы


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119631/excel-date-conversion-using-php-excel

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is your problem in getting the date from MS SQL as a date/time, or setting the Excel date?

There is a whole section of the PHPExcel documentation that explains the use of the `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel($PHPDate)` and `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::FormattedPHPToExcel($year, $month, $day, $hours=0, $minutes=0, $seconds=0)` helper methods for converting PHP dates to an Excel datetime stamp value that you set as the cell value, and then you apply a number format mask of one of the date masks such as `PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDD2` to that cell

Instead of

```
$t_year     = substr($xls_column_datas["colname"],0,4);    
$t_month    = substr($xls_column_datas["colname"],5,2);    
$t_day      = substr($xls_column_datas["colname"],8,2);
$t_format   = '=date('.$t_format.')';
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($data_column_num, $data_row_num, $t_format );
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyleByColumnAndRow($data_column_num, $data_row_num)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('[$-C09]d mmm yyyy;@');
```

try setting

```
$t_year   = substr($xls_column_datas["colname"],0,4);
$t_month  = substr($xls_column_datas["colname"],4,2);  // Fixed problems with offsets
$t_day    = substr($xls_column_datas["colname"],6,2);
$t_date   = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::FormattedPHPToExcel($t_year, $t_month, $t_day);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(
    $data_column_num, $data_row_num, $t_date 
);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyleByColumnAndRow($data_column_num, $data_row_num)
    ->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(
        PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_XLSX14
    );
```

Comment: Hmm but this sets the cell format to NUMBER and it seems like 43073.4250578704 in the exported file. But there is also the DATE format for cells BUT no getDateFormat() function in PHPExcel. I dont understand it.

Comment: May be cause I see it in Open Office?

Comment: Nothing to do with opening in OpenOffiice.... `PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_XLSX14` is the format being set in this code example, and it is not a number format, but a date format

Comment: I have almost the same code    
```$list->setCellValueByColumnAndRow( ++$column, $row,  \PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel( $survey->task->closed )' )->getStyle()->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode( \PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DDMMYYYY );``` but looks as I write before?

Comment: Ask  question - a proper question, showing appropriate code, and not simply comments against an answer to somebody else's question - and I'll look at it..... but perhaps don't try fluent setting getStyle() from setCellValue().... use two separate statements

Comment: Ok can you look at my question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48518427/phpexcel-setcellvaluebycolumnandrow-to-datetime-cell-format

Comment: It seems you are right. The fluent call getStyle() does not work. Must call ->getStyleByColumnAndRow() on excel sheet object.

Answer (score 8):

```
$date = PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::toFormattedString($data, "M/D/YYYY");
```

Answer (score 1):

Though it is unclear what are asking, If you are looking for a date conversion

```
 // convert old date string to YYYYmmdd format
    $date = date('d M Y', strtotime($old_date));
```

this will output date in 09 Aug 2012 format

Answer (score 1):

Why not let the server to the formatting for you? Use this query to format the date

```
SELECT convert(varchar(15), getdate(), 106)
```

This will result `11 Sep 2012`

**[SQL SERVER: Date Format](https://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/)**