# PHPExcel setCellValueByColumnAndRow() to datetime cell format

Tags: php, date, datetime, phpexcel

Hi can somebody tell me how to set phpexcel cell format to datetime if I have datatime in php variable? I use it this way but it is only string:

```
$list->setCellValueByColumnAndRow( ++$column, $row, $survey->task->closed->format(DateTimeUtils::DATE_FORMAT_NO_SPACES) );
```

**EDIT:**
Now I have this code:

```
$list->setCellValueByColumnAndRow( ++$column, $row, \PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel( $survey->task->closed ) )
->getStyle()->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(\PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DDMMYYYY);
```

but it sets the cell format to number and date seems in result like float number 43098.4755671296

Answer (score 0):

It seems the fluent call **getStyle()** does not work and should be called **getStyleByColumnAndRow()** instead on excel sheet object.

```
$activeSheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow( $column, $row, $survey)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode( \PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DDMMYYYY );
```

I am confused and don't understand what is the difference between **getStyle()** and **getStyleByColumnAndRow()**. 
If somebody knows let me know.

EDIT: There is fourth parameter in setCellValueByColumnAndRow() method which determines return value. Fluent getStyle() needs to set it to TRUE.