# Read excel date value to m-d-Y in php

Tags: php

In my php project i need to import an excel file and insert all the values to the table.
I am using `phpExcelReader` to import file..
In y excel file there is column for storing date values in the format d/m/Y. But when i read these value it's not correct 
foe example i have given the date as '`25/02/2013`' and it will result `TueTue/FebFeb/2013201320132013`

See the code

```
require_once 'Excel/reader.php';
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
$data->setOutputEncoding('CP1251');
//echo $target_path;
$data->read('uploads/initiativeData/'.$uploadFile);     
$startDate=trim(mysql_escape_string($data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][5]));
```

here $startDate is the variable to store the date field value

I need to get the value as `02-25-2013`.. does any one know this

Please reply

Thanks

Comment: The answer is in the post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119631/excel-date-conversion-using-php-excel

Answer (score 2):

This has solved the problem for me:

```
$data->sheets[$sheetNumber]['cellsInfo'][$rowNumber][$cellNumber]['raw'];
```

It will give you the date in timestamp format
where:

```
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
$data->read("YourFile.xls");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime), it should be able to parse your date string. After that you can convert it to any format you want with [date](http://php.net/date). E.g:

```
$yourData = date('d.m.Y', strtotime(trim($data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][5])));
```

**Edit:**

```
$yourData = date('d.m.Y', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', trim($data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][5]))));
```

Comment: i have tried this but i got the date as 01.01.1970, actually the result is  02-25-2013

Comment: Just updated my answer, it seems that `strtotime` is not that cool as I thought. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help. But still it' not work. i got the result as '01.01.1970'. Please help me

Comment: `echo date('d.m.Y', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', trim('25/02/2013'))));` works for me.

Comment: yes it's working for me when i give the date as manual. Please note i am reading the date from an excel sheet.. So the result is not 25/02/2013, its 'TueTue/FebFeb/2013201320132013'

Comment: i am using same lib ,but in my excel sheet date is 08/29/2013. php is get is this value ->AugAug/TueTue/2013201320132013. what is issue please help me

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a [`DateTime::createFromFormat()` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), which will do exactly what you want.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '25/02/2013');  //import with the specified format...
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');   //...and now you can output it in whatever format you want.
```

Answer (score 0):

In [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) there are 2 different functions to get the value for a field.

```
$value  = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getCell('B12')->getValue();
$value2 = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getCell('B12')->getCalculatedValue();
```

I am not sure if the different functions also exist in the phpExcelReader library you are using, but it's worth looking into.

On looking a bit further, this is in the documentation:

```
Accessing Cell Values

It is recommended that the public API functions be used to access data rather than relying on the underlying data structure, which may change between releases.

Retrieve the formatted value of a cell (what is displayed by Excel) on the first (or only) worksheet:

    $data->val($row,$col) 

You can also use column names rather than numbers:

    $data->val(10,'AZ') 

Access data on a different sheet:

    $data->val($row,$col,$sheet_index)
```

So try using the val() function to get the value, instead of the method you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader Class

Replace this function :

```
function createDate($numValue) {
        if ($numValue > 1) {
            $utcDays = $numValue - ($this->nineteenFour ? SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_UTCOFFSETDAYS1904 : SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_UTCOFFSETDAYS);
            $utcValue = round(($utcDays) * SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_MSINADAY);

            $this->curformat = strtolower($this->curformat);
            //echo $this->curformat; echo "<br>";
            if ($this->curformat == 'mm/dd/yyyy' || $this->curformat == 'i/dd/yyyy') {
                $this->curformat = 'Y-m-d';
            }

            $string = date($this->curformat, $utcValue);
            $raw = $utcValue;
        } else {
            $raw = $numValue;
            $hours = floor($numValue * 24);
            $mins = floor($numValue * 24 * 60) - $hours * 60;
            $secs = floor($numValue * SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_MSINADAY) - $hours * 60 * 60 - $mins * 60;
            $string = date($this->curformat, mktime($hours, $mins, $secs));
        }

        return array($string, $raw);
    }
```