# Time is shown as number

Tags: php, sql, csv, ms-access, phpexcel

Greetins, I have a problem with date and time in php. The thing is, that date, which should be as: **8/5/15  2:27**  is shown like: **42221.102083333** ANyone knows how to convert it back?

```
$convertdate = date("y/m/d", $string);
//NOT WORKING
```

**EDIT**

```
$seconds = $data[11];
$convertdate = date("y/m/d", $seconds);
```

$data[11] = 42221.102083333

Comment: Please post the full code.

Comment: [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) gets an integer as a second parameter, not a string...

Comment: `date()` expects a unix-epoch timestamp as its second argument. For example, the current timestamp, generated by `time();`, is (or was a few seconds ago) 1451765676.

Where is this timestamp coming from?

Comment: In edit I added how I'm trying to convert date. Time is shown as 8/5/15 2:27 in .xlsx file, i'm converting file to .csv format, after conversion, date becomes: 42221.102083333

Comment: Got it. Here's a question: what value do you get if you put the current time into the excel file?

Is it something like 42602.8866246?

Comment: Yes, in my xlsx file, there is more than 10.000 dates. They are in format like: 8/5/15 2:27. After conversion, they all becomes something like: 42221.102083333 - just differs as date and time differs in excel file.

Comment: This might help: http://fczaja.blogspot.com/2011/06/convert-excel-date-into-timestamp.html

Comment: Those numbers are DateTime serial numbers, it's how Excel stores Dates/Times under the hood.  What you see on the sheet is that number _Formatted_ as Date and or Time.  It's up to your code to deal with that when generating the csv.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel date conversion using PHP Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119631/excel-date-conversion-using-php-excel)

Comment: Lines: $date_int_val = $data[11];
   $date_formated = date('Y-m-d', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($date_int_val)); Did the trick. thans everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This line solved my problem :)**

```
 $date_int_val = $data[11];
    $date_formated = date('Y-m-d', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($date_int_val));
```