# PHP: How to convert VARIANT DATE to datetime string

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

In my project, I get from external system date & time in `VARIANT DATE` type .

I need to convert it to datetime, i.e., `44768.25` => `2022-07-26 06:06:40`.

Do you know how to do it in PHP? What is the best approach?

Comment: `44768.25` <--- I suspect this is coming from an excel sheet?

Comment: Yes, I am importing Excel to get data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel date conversion using PHP Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119631/excel-date-conversion-using-php-excel)

Answer (score 2):

Use this formula to change from Excel date to Unix date,

then you can use "gmdate" to get the real date in PHP:

```
UNIX_DATE = (EXCEL_DATE - 25569) * 86400
```

The 86400 is the number of seconds in a day = 24 * 60 * 60.

The 25569 is the number of days from Jan 1, 1900 to Jan 1, 1970.

Excel base date is Jan 1, 1900 and Unix is Jan 1, 1970.

UNIX date values are in seconds from Jan 1, 1970 (midnight Dec 31, 1969).

So to convert from excel you must subtract the number of days and then convert to seconds.

```
$EXCEL_DATE = 44768.25;
$UNIX_DATE = ($EXCEL_DATE - 25569) * 86400;
echo gmdate("d-m-Y H:i:s", $UNIX_DATE);
```

You will get output as 26-07-2022 06:00:00